# I want to add a few dependencies in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website in laravel but at the checkout time it's showing 500 error

I searched for solutions and someone told me to do add some code in composer dependies and update composer
But I'm unable to find in which file I have to add the code
Can you guys guide me

Here is the code

"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0"

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/747

Comment: composer.json should be in root folder of your project. Or, you can simply run in terminal/cmd composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: can you check the log file

Answer (score 0):

All PHP Dependencies are mentioned in `composer.json` file which is located on root of the project.

1. Add `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0"` this to your `composer.json`.
2. Open Your terminal.
3. `cd your_project_path`.
4. Run `composer dump-autoload`.

Or add dependency via composer

1. Open terminal.
2. `cd your_project_path`.
3. `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`.

Comment: Thanks  I just add the code in composer.json and than update composer by composer update command .